# Get the total number of group names where there are multiple group names in a single cell surrounded by random text

Tags: excel, powershell, sharepoint, excel-formula

This is regarding an export of a list from a Sharepoint site where I do not have access to exporting feature, but I can refresh the information in order to gather new information when is added on the Sharepoint site. 
The excel list has several columns, out of which one of them is containing names of groups that were created.

There are several thousands of rows, with cells where each cell might contain this kind of data. 
I want to be able to only count the number of groups in my excel sheet.

I was initially thinking to find a way to export somehow the data as text and to then try to remove any parts in the string BEFORE the rows (again, all these rows are in the same cell) in order to make the data uniform and to have only the name of the groups and then to try count in a different column the number of items in each cell and to have a sum.

```
"Please delete following CORP group: 

PRD.12.SYOS.EXOA.XW12LAPP0171.TWSUSERS
PRD.12.SYOS.XW12LAPP0171.Administrators
PRD.12.SYOS.EXOA.XW12LAPP0063.TWSAGENT
PRD.12.SYOS.EXOA.XW12LAPP0063.TWSUSERS
PRD.12.SYOS.VM4P.XW12LAPP0063.ADMINISTRATORS
PRD.12.SYOS.VM4P.XW12LAPP0063.RDP
PRD.12.SYOS.XW12LAPP0063.Administrators"
```

I am a beginner in excel and in coding. I tried using functions in excel like RIGHT, LEFT, MID, LEN but I am still unable to produce anything close to what I need.

I need the total number of the groups in the sheet.

Comment: So with the sample data provided, would the count be 4? And, does the text in the cell include the `"` or not?

Comment: With the sample data the answer would be 7.

Comment: Why is this tagged `PowerShell`?

Comment: Somehow I thought this might be solved using PowerShell

Answer (score 1):

with a helper column you could extract the part after the last dot [with](http://www.excelformeln.de/formeln.html?welcher=301)

```
=MID(A1,LOOKUP(9^9,FIND(".",A1,ROW(1:999)))+1,50)
```

and then count the number of unique group names, which occur [with](http://www.excelformeln.de/formeln.html?welcher=42)

```
=SUMPRODUCT((E1:E99<>"")/COUNTIF(E1:E99,E1:E99&""))
```

Be aware of the fact, that each `Administrators` and `Administrators"` get counted as a unique group. You need to strip off unnecessary chars with `SUBSTITUTE` if you dont want that behaviour.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When your list doesn't have doublures you could use a rather simple formula like:

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHR(10),""))-1
```

It would also be a nice issue to use `REGEX` on, like so for example:

```
Function CountGroup(RNG As Range) As Double

Dim regex As Object
Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With regex
    .Pattern = "(?=.*\d)[^\n " & Chr(34) & "]+"
    .Global = True
End With
Set Matches = regex.Execute(RNG.Value)
CountGroup = Matches.Count

End Function
```

Or when your list **can** contain doublures:

```
Function CountGroup(RNG As Range) As Double

Dim regex As Object, ARR1() As String, X As Long, ARR2() As String
Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With regex
    .Pattern = "(?=.*\d)[^\n " & Chr(34) & "]+"
    .Global = True
End With
Set matches = regex.Execute(RNG.Value)
ReDim ARR1(X)
For Each HIT In matches
    ARR2 = Filter(SourceArray:=ARR1, Match:=HIT.Value, Include:=True, Compare:=vbTextCompare)
    If UBound(ARR2) = -1 Then
        ReDim Preserve ARR1(X)
        ARR1(X) = HIT.Value
        X = X + 1
    End If
Next HIT

If IsEmpty(ARR1) Then
    CountGroup = 0
Else
    CountGroup = UBound(ARR1) - LBound(ARR1)
End If

End Function
```

Call in sheet through `=CountGroup(A1)`

[image]